# How to get class name in logs in which winston logger is called

Tags: node.js, nestjs, winston

I am creating NestJS application in which I am using winston logger for logging purposes.I am getting logs inside log file but along with logs I also want the class name in which logger is called so that it can easily be identified which logs are producing by which class.

Below is my winston setup:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WinstonModule,utilities as nestWinstonModuleUtilities } from 'nest-winston';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TestModule } from './test/test.module';
import * as path from 'path';

@Module({
imports: [ WinstonModule.forRoot({
          transports: [
                      new winston.transports.Console({
                        level: 'info',
                        format:winston.format.combine(
                          winston.format.colorize(),
                          winston.format.timestamp({
                            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
                           }),
                          winston.format.printf(
                            info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
                          ),
                         )
                      }),
                      new winston.transports.File({
                      dirname: path.join(__dirname, '../log/info/'), //path to where save logging result 
                      filename: 'info.log', //name of file where will be saved logging result
                      level: 'info',
                      format:winston.format.combine(
                         winston.format.timestamp({
                          format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
                         }),
                        winston.format.printf(
                          info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`
                        )
                      ),
                    }),
                  ],        
       }), TestModule,],
controllers: [AppController],
providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Logger } from 'winston';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor( @Inject('winston') private readonly logger: Logger){}

  getHello(): string {
   this.logger.info('Hello logs');
   return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

Here logger is called by `AppService` class so I want this classname  also in logs.How can I achieve desired result

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by not injecting the logger, but directly creating a new instance.

```js
export class AppService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AppService.name); 

  constructor(...)
}
```

Unfortunately you loose the advantages of dependency injection. For exmaple you need special way to mock it in tests. But it's possible.

It still works if you registered a custom logger. For example when you are using winston logger, the solution will also get you the Winton Logger.:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: WinstonModule.createLogger({
      exitOnError: false,
      format: format.json(),
      transports: [
        new transports.Console({
          format: format.combine(
            format.simple(),
            format.timestamp(),
            format.ms(),
            format.errors({ stack: true }),
            utilities.format.nestLike()
          )
        })
      ],
      level: process.env.WINSTON_LOGGING ?? 'info'
    })
});
```

You can mock it the same way, for example for tests:

```js
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  // ...
}).compile();
const app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
app.useLogger(loggerMock);
```

Comment: It will not instantiate Winston logger rather it will instantiate the NestJs built in Logger.

Comment: @Digvijay Actually it initialized the winston logger. I updated my answer.